# How to make a BaseUserControl meant for inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, user-controls

I need to create a BaseUserControl that has some custom code behind and inherits from UserControl, so it could be used as a ParrentClass for, actually to be used, UserControls. I have read numerous articles but I can simply not get it to work.
The BaseUserControl is not supossed to have any design elements but purely custom stuff like references to be used in other UserControls that will inherit from it, but design element would be apriciated. I will require more baseUseControls like this so Exstensions are out of the question.
The  BaseUsercontrol is in one project, and the rest that inherits it is in another.

1) I tried to create only a class that inherits.

```
public class EntryUserControlBase:UserControl
{
    public EntryUserControlBase()
    {

    }
}
```

2) Also a inheriting from a UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="SPIS_Base.EntryUserControlBase"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I tried to inherit it like this

```
<local:EntryUserControlBase x:Class="SPIS.AppControls.uclLogin"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SPIS_Base;assembly=SPIS_Base"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ShowGridLines="False">

    </Grid>
</local:EntryUserControlBase>
```

I found many articles that explain how to do it, but I cant get it to run.

Any tips?

Comment: Did you try abstract?

Comment: That last <local:EntryUserControlBase x:Class="SPIS.AppControls.uclLogin" should work. I have an example here that is working. Have you checked the codebehind file? Maybe inheritance is missing there. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: no, inheritance is not missing. With it  I am getting a message that it can not inherrit from XAML. The first way I am getting a message "Cannot find the type 'local:CustomControl1'. Note that type names are case sensitive. Line 7 Position 12."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the following to inherit base properties and functions in usercontrols.

```cs
//Base class
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace Controls
{
    public class BaseUserControl: UserControl
    {
        protected string getText()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
} 

//Sub class
<Controls:BaseUserControl x:Class="MyNameSpace.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Controls;assembly=MyAssembly">
</Controls:BaseUserControl>

using Controls;
public partial class MyUserControl : BaseUserControl
{
    public MyUserControl ()
    {
        var baseText = getText();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WPF does not allow this kind of 'visual inheritance' like you could achieve in WinForms, where the base class has a designed UI (in this case, a XAML definition.)  This only worked in WinForms because of the way that it generated the designer code for building up the UserControl or Form contents.  XAML parsing is a completely different approach and 'merging' the content of two XAML files is not a well-defined operation.

There are various compositional ways to accomplish the same kind of goal in WPF.  Some examples:

1. Create a custom control (not a UserControl) that properly supports a [Control Template](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14340/Creating-a-look-less-custom-control-in-WPF).  This allows you to define points of extensibility, such as places to put embedded "Content" in the control.
2. Define a Style that allows applying 'base' properties to a UserControl.  This is less flexible than a full control template design, but easier to implement.

Comment: Its more a thing of having different methods in the baseUserControl

Comment: I finally made it to inherit it using the first method. I am creating the inheritance-top usercontrol and trying to set it a style. How can I set the background to it.
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:EntryUserControlBase}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
  </Style>                                                                         It does not freaking work !!! I tried everything but the sytle simply stays null.